# Traversing multi-way tree, computational complexity

Tags: computational-complexity, trees

This is a computational challenge. I am looking for a clever simplification or heuristic.

Imagine a multi-way tree. Each node has three child branches. Consider them to be decisions; do A, do B, do C. Further imagine you're tracing a path from root to every leaf node, a trajectory.

Example:

```
                   Root
 |   |   |        |  |   |        |    |   | 
A1, B1, C1       A2, B2, C2       A1, B1, C1
```

Say you have a tree of $3$ levels. Root is at $0.$ Then number of nodes $3^0 + 3^1 + 3^2 + 3^3 = 1+3+9+27 = 40 = (3^{(n+1)}-1)/2 = (3^4-1)/2.$ On the last level, there are $3^3=27$ or $3^n$ nodes, or more specifically trajectories.

I can't traverse this tree after $n>20$ and I need to explore $n=500$ which is $3^{500}.$ In my domain, I am assigning a cost to each decision (money/points/weights). Now, I am only interested in the top $5$ and bottom $5$ trajectories according to my cost function.

Does anybody think there is a way of finding maximum and minimum of this tree given some cost function without exploring $3^n$ paths? Or knows other ways of reducing the sample space.

Thank you

Comment: What search/optimization algorithms do you know (e.g. branch and bound, A*)? Which ones have you considered using?

Comment: David, I don't know many. I considered a random sampling of trajectories in order to find min/max. I am not able to derive how quickly, if ever random search will converge on the max/min.